# Adobe Muse,Mobile,Page layout,Left aligned,Right side gap,

Tags: mobile-website, page-layout

I have created a website using Adobe Muse and have uploaded the site to the ftp server . The website is live and is as designed when looked via a desktop. But when the same site is being viewed from a mobile, the entire page is getting left aligned and there is a gap to the right side. I even made a phone layout and uploaded the same to the ftp server and the problem still persists. Ive googled a lot and inserted html code into the metadata to make the site centered but in vain. Nothing works . I have a tight deadline and would really be grateful for any quick help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your images are placed in pixels... If I am right
try using a rectangular tool... fill it with image then make the width 100%

to view the sample image [click here](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10378250_933301960022761_4004009316023420430_n.jpg?oh=32675100ced7bafcd60a175fda3c93e3&oe=54E39025&__gda__=1424210970_f0641f29deca2c42c99251330aeb33c2)

The size of mobile layout in muse is fix... I think the mobile you are using have different size... so just start using % on placing the images like the background etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting that was causing my content to be left-aligned in the phone layout.

1. Click Page > Page Properties
2. There's an un-marked button to the far right of Padding - click this and set it to centered. By default it is left-aligned.

[image]